# Line is not centered between edges of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this small tree and I want to draw a line between the edges from node A to node B.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, level distance=1.5cm,
  every node/.style={draw, thick, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, sibling distance=4cm, transform shape}]

\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\Tree [ . \node (R){Crack password};
                            \node (A) {Acquire shadow file};
                            \node (B) {Acquire passwd file};
                        ]

\path (R) -- coordinate[left] (PA) (A);
\path (R) -- coordinate[right] (PB) (B);

\draw (PA) to[bend right=25] (PB);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Picture of the problem]

As we can see in the picture the bend line is being offset to the right. And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `north` and `south` when you draw the paths between the nodes.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, level distance=1.5cm,
  every node/.style={draw, thick, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, sibling distance=4cm, transform shape}]

\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\Tree [ . \node (R){Crack password};
                            \node (A) {Acquire shadow file};
                            \node (B) {Acquire passwd file};
                        ]

\path (R.south) -- coordinate[left] (PA) (A.north);
\path (R.south) -- coordinate[right] (PB) (B.north);

\draw (PA) to[bend right=25] (PB);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Stene You're welcome, sir! :D